# how to copy data between two DML forms Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, forms, copy, oracle-apex, dml

I am using Oracle APEX 4.2.5

I have two different DML form with same design one for Creating new Record (Create Record form) and one for editing the data (update Record form).

If I update the design of "Create Record" form by including few more data points, same need to be redesigned for "update Record form". Is there any way where I copy the Fields from one form to another ?